# Devise redirect after sign in for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

`Rails 5.2`

I have two devise models `User, Worker`

User and Worker have their own separate devise generated views

I configured my application controller with `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # redirect after sign-in
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource
    when User
      resource.update_attribute(:active, true)
      dashboard_path(current_user.id)
    when Worker
      faq_path
    end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource) 
    # request.referer
    root_path
  end 

end
```

However, no matter the configuration, the user is redirected to root_path on sign-in.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Maybe resource.is_a? Instead of the plain call? I think the latter returns the user object, so it isn’t equal to User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you routes you can do something like this

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
  }

  devise_for :workers, controllers: {
    sessions: 'workers/sessions',
    registrations: 'workers/registrations'
  }
```

And then you can create the corresponding files in /app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb - /app/controllers/workers/sessions_controllers.rb etc. depending what you described in your routes.rb file.

And then, in those file you can implement your custom methods like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)
    users_root_path # or whatever path you want here
  end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

And this is a cleaner solution for each resource instead of comparing the class and you have the freedom to customize/override any method in there for the specific resource without complicating your code.

I hope this helps.